# Cannot spawn an erlang supervisor from the shell

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I've implemented a gen_server and supervisor: `test_server` and `test_sup`. I want to test them from the shell/CLI. I've written their `start_link` functions such that their names are registered locally.

I've found that I can spawn the `test_server` from the command line just fine, but a spawned `test_sup` does not allow me to interact with the server at all.

For example, I can spawn a `test_server` by executing:

```
1> spawn(test_server, start_link, []).
<0.39.0>
2> registered().
[...,test_server,...]
```

I can interact with the server, and everything appears fine.

However, if I try to do the same thing with `test_sup`, no new names/Pids are registered in my "CLI process" (using `registered/0`). My `test_server` appears to have been spawned, but I cannot interact with it (see Lukas Larsson's comment about SASL to see why this is true).

I'd assume I coded an error in my supervisor, but this method of starting my supervisor works perfectly fine:

```
1> {ok, Pid}= test_sup:start_link([]).
{ok, <0.39.0>}
2> unlink(Pid).
true
3> registered().
[...,test_server,test_sup,...]
```

Why is it that I can spawn a gen_server but not a supervisor?

---

**Update**

The code I'm using can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775114/erlang-otp-supervisor-crashing). I'm using `echo_server` and `echo_sup`, two very simple modules.

Given that code, this works:

```
spawn(echo_server, start_link, []).
```

and this does not:

```
spawn(echo_sup, start_link, []).
```

Comment: Can you paste your code somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This explanation was given by Bernard Duggan on the [Erlang questions mailing list](http://forum.trapexit.org/mailinglists/viewtopic.php?t=18373):

> Linked processes don't automatically
>   die when a process they are linked to
>   exits with code 'normal'.  That's why
>   [echo_server] doesn't exit when the
>   spawning process exits.  So why does
>   the supervisor die?  The internals of
>   the supervisor module are in fact
>   themselves implemented as a
>   gen_server, but with
>   process_flag(trap_exit, true) set. 
>   The result of this is that when the
>   parent process dies, terminate() gets
>   called (which doesn't happen when
>   trap_exit is disabled) and the
>   supervisor shuts down.  It makes sense
>   in the context of a supervisor, since
>   a supervisor is spawned by its parent
>   in a supervision tree - if it didn't
>   die whenever its parent shutdown,
>   whatever the reason, you'd have
>   dangling "branches" of the tree.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever trying to figure these things out it is usually very helpful to switch on SASL.

application:start(sasl).

That way you will hopefully get to know why you supervisor is terminating.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be terminating. After starting SASL, I get a Progress Report that says echo_sup and echo_server were started, but the echo_server is not accessible from the command line after that.

Comment: I'd have to see your supervisor code and your gen_server to help you more. There is probably just something small that you are missing.

Comment: I linked to the code in update #1. [Here's the link again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775114/erlang-otp-supervisor-crashing)