# How do I start applications by command line as a daemon?

Tags: erlang

This has been my current routine

```
sudo nohup erl -sname foo -pa ./ebin -run foo_supervisor shell -noshell -noinput &
```

where the shell function looks something like this

```
shell() ->
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_link({local,?MODULE}, ?MODULE, _Arg = []),
    unlink(Pid).
```

If I don't unlink from shell it immediately stops for some reason. Is there a way I can just start my application like I would normally ie application:start(foo). Also what if I want to start sasl too? Also where could I learn more about making a self contained package using rebar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preface. About your unlink**

In [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775114/erlang-otp-supervisor-crashing) @filippo explains why you need the `unlink` when testing supervisors from the shell.

**First. What you need is an [Erlang application](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/application.html).**

Reading from the doc:

> In OTP, application denotes a
>   component implementing some specific
>   functionality, that can be started and
>   stopped as a unit, and which can be
>   re-used in other systems as well.

Details on how to implement an Erlang application are available [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html). The three main things you will need to do are:

- [Have a proper directory structure](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#app_dir) for your application
- Write an [application callback module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id70918) implementing the Erlang application behaviour. That's where you will start your root supervisor
- [Provide an application resource file](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#appl_res_file). This is where you tell the system - among other things - where to find your application callback module (look at the `mod` parameter).

**Second. Starting SASL.**

In the above application resource file, you can specify a list of applications you want to start before your application. You will add something like:

```
...
{applications, [kernel, stdlib, sasl]},
...
```

To tell it to start SASL.

**Third. Rebar.**

There's an introduction to Rebar [here](http://alancastro.org/2010/05/01/erlang-application-management-with-rebar.html), which explains you how to use Rebar to help you in the above steps, to pack your brand new application into an [Erlang release](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html) and how to start it.