# Erlang Module Crashes when started from shell

Tags: erlang

Got a module that should keep running in the background as a tcp server waiting and serving connections.

When I start my module by first running erlang shell and then calling my module, it works fine,

However, if I run it directly via erl -s or -eval -run etc, Supervisor that supervises tcp server complains *no match for the right hand side..{error, closed}* and fails.

System:Ubuntu 18

**Update**:
[Here is what might be wrong, Working on it...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174079/problem-with-starting-supervisor-through-script-erlang)

**Update:** Solved by unlinking supervisor for now, will use proper releases in future.

Comment: It's difficult to help you since you didn't post your code, but I'd guess you have a `gen_tcp:recv/2,3` call somewhere that isn't handling `{error, closed}`.

Comment: Issue seems to be on accept, maybe its not letting it wait for connections, Feels like its terminating running code before returning back on me, it shouldn't @SteveVinoski

Comment: A closed listen socket makes `accept` return `{error, closed}`, so make sure the process owning the listen socket isn't dying and taking that socket down with it.

Comment: thats the issue, why is it dying when started directly using erl -s but NOT dying when started from erlang shell?

Comment: I would have to see your code and see how you're using the shell to be able to answer that.

Comment: Currently in the process of making rel, if it doesnt work, will post relevant code