# Why doesn't spawn link cause the calling process to die?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

From the example given here, [Erlang and process_flag(trap_exit, true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720472/erlang-and-process-flagtrap-exit-true)

```
-module(play).
-compile(export_all).

start() ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    spawn_link(?MODULE, inverse, [***0***]),
    loop().

loop() ->
    receive
        Msg -> io:format("~p~n", [Msg])
    end,
    loop().

inverse(N) -> 1/N.
```

If I run it as,

```
A = spawn(play, start, []).
```

The spawned process <0.40.0> dies as it is suppose to but the main process (A <0.39.0>) which spawned it doesn't die.

```
{'EXIT',<0.40.0>,{badarith,[{play,inverse,1,[{file,"play.erl"},{line,15}]}]}}
<0.39.0>
i().
....
....
<0.39.0>              play:start/0                           233       19    0
                  play:loop/0                              1
```

A does get an exit signal (not an exit message since A is not trapping exit) then why doesn't it exit?

Comment: What version of Erlang/OTP are you using? On 17.4, `spawn_link(erlang, div, [1, 0])` kills the shell process that spawned it. It's possible that in later (or earlier) versions they added exit trapping to shell processes.

Comment: erl -v
    Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.2] [source-aaaefb3] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-   threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
    Eshell V6.2  (abort with ^G)

Comment: Shell is killed by div by 0 for me as well 2> self().
<0.36.0>
3> spawn_link(fun() -> 1/0 end).        

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-Jun-2015::16:21:47 ===
Error in process <0.39.0> with exit value: {badarith,[{erlang,'/',[1,0],[]}]}

** exception exit: badarith
     in operator  '/'/2
        called as 1 / 0
4> self().
<0.40.0>
5>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that you set a `trap_exit` flag to `true` which means this process will get `{'EXIT', FromPid, Reason}` message instead of being killed. Just remove `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` or in case of receiving this type of message, kill it.

You can read about it [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id85009).